# VSCode adding white space to render() output while saved

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I am trying to edit an App.js file. Every time I try and save the project, white spaces are being added to the markup inside the parentheses of the return method.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class App extends Component {
render() {
    return ( <div></div>);
    }
}
```

Notice how the spaces are being added to the div tags.
I would show the actual code but stack overflow will not allow for improper spacing.

Does anyone have a solution? Google or Stack Overflow doesn't seem to have the solutions I need.

Comment: This is not an accurate portrayal of the problem. When saving, "<div></div>" becomes "< div > < / div >"

Comment: Do you have some sort of beautifier installed maybe? Check your extensions

Comment: I have no beautifier extension